# how many randomizations does chisquare in scipy do?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm diving into statistics and learned that one calculates P (the probability that an observed outcome is by chance) by creating random permutations and check the probability of the observed outcome against that random distribution.

I wonder why chisquare does not have a `number_of_randomizations` or so parameter. How many randomizations is it doing or how is it calculating P?

Comment: Are you talking about `scipy.stats.chisquare` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html)?

Comment: You probably partly misunderstood what you read --- that that is the way p-values are usually calculated in practice, and that it is the only way to calculate them. The answer to the question on "how many randomizations" is that the calculation is done in a completely different way (and under standard statistics textbook assumptions). The question has no answer since the assumptions behind the question do not apply.